# What's the proper way to keep UITabBar in all ViewControllers (Don't want to use UITabBarController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

Just to clarify things, I **don't** want to use `UITabBarController`. I need to do some custom changes to the `UITabBar` that can't be done using `UITabBarController`. (like making it scroll etc')

This is how I've created my `UITabBar`

1. From the Interface Builder I've dragged a `UITabBar` and located it inside a `ViewController`s.
2. Connected the delegate and outlet.
3. Added `UITabbarItem` tags and segue identifier.

and used this code:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
   {
      if (item.tag==0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Favorite" sender:nil];
      }
      else if (item.tag==1)
      {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Item" sender:nil];
      }
   }
```

My problem is that when I push a new `ViewController` the `UITabBar` disappears. 
My question is, what's the right proper way to keep the `UITabBar` on the pushed `ViewController` and other `ViewController`s ?

I've tried passing it to the next view controller using `PrepareForSegue` and it works but when I go back to my previous controller I need to reset the `UITabBar` frame etc'. I guess I can keep it as a global object inside my Singleton and keep adding it to new `ViewController`s but that sounds like an over kill
Is there a better way to do it without using a `UITabBarController` ?

Comment: why not you are using a Tabbar based application? Is there any specific requirement? If you will use UITabBar in this way it will create so many frame based issue.

Comment: I want the `UITabBar`to be scrollable .. question edited.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't want to use a tab bar controller, you should still follow the same design pattern. Your `ScrollableTabBarController` should be a container view controller, and when different tab items are selected, it should add the new item as a child view controller. Read the view controller containment documentation for more details.

At the moment it sounds like you're pushing view controllers on top of your container, which suggests that your storyboard is based on a navigation controller. This is the wrong way to do it.

I'm not sure how straightforward it is to do custom container controllers in the storyboard, (I'd do it in code). You may have to make the connections manually rather than via segues.